# Insufficient privileges for accessing data in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am following the tutorial on [Getting Started (Console) - Amazon Personalize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/getting-started-console.html) of the recommendation engine on Amazon SageMaker. 
When importing `User-item` interaction data, I got the following error:

> There was an error with your dataset import
>
> Insufficient privileges for accessing data in S3. Please look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/getting-started.html#gs-upload-to-bucket and fix the bucket policy on `recommendation123`.

I have tried different bucket policies but none of them is allowing to import the data.

The user-item interaction data flag should change from failed to active.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set list and get permissions to your bucket, in a bucket policy, not in the role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "personalize.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-dev-personalize"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "personalize.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-dev-personalize/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had changed the bucket policy in s3 only. {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "PersonalizeS3BucketAccessPolicy",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "PersonalizeS3BucketAccessPolicy",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": {
               "Service": "personalize.amazonaws.com"
           },
           "Action": [
               "s3:GetObject",
               "s3:ListBucket"
           ],
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::recommendation123",
               "arn:aws:s3:::recommendation123/*"
           ]
       }
   ]
}