# Insufficient privileges for accessing data in S3 - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been trying to access S3 resource to use in AWS Personalize. Whenever I try, I get below error. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553948/insufficient-privileges-for-accessing-data-in-s3) question and created policy for S3.

```
Insufficient privileges for accessing data in S3. Please look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/getting-started.html#gs-upload-to-bucket and fix bucket policy on personalize123.
```

AWS Bucket Permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1584771703282",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1584771695535",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::289126069598:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::personalize123/ratings.csv"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your bucket policy permissions?

Comment: @RichardRublev: Have added permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Personalize needs permission to access the S3 bucket. You must enable ListBucket nad GetObject actions. 
Try to edit this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "personalize.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yourbucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "personalize.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yourbucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Read [Uploading to an S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/data-prep-upload-s3.html)

Comment: I'm using the correct bucket policy but I'm getting the same error. 
Here is my policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PersonalizeS3BucketAccessPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PersonalizeS3BucketAccessPolicy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucker-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}